# HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

### Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found. 
  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /login.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

Comment: i get error while publishing my project into iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Right click your project in **Visual Studio** -> **Properties** -> **Web** (left hand tab) -> **Specific Page** with an empty string as the name.

Comment: thnx for your comment @salah salah ...appreciate that...in web config i had commented the form tag which contain login.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For reference, make sure that `area` ,`controller` , and `method` are also specified along with the `action` name within  the url you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

May help someone down the line, but another tip would be under your Application properties > Web > Enable 'Current Page'.  This helped me with a similar issue.